# What is ApplicationMaster node on Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop

Firstly, I saw my running job is handled by 1 application master node, which is not a master node (different IP address). Thus I thought my job is processed by only 1 node. But when I checked where the mapper jobs were processed, they were actually processed by other slave nodes.

I'm a bit confused because I thought the master node will be also the Application master, who will handle the job management. But in this case it is not.

Can someone help me to understand why the current management for my job is handled by a slave node (which is called application master), and not by my master node ?

Another question is the master node in hadoop is considered as a single point of failure, but when we have a secondary node, it will be fine. For the application master node case, should it also be considered as a single point of failure ? Since if the slave node is down, there will be no backup for it as I understand.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Application Master is not a node in the same sense as a Master node or Slave node - it does not represent a machine in your cluster. The Application Master is a YARN process used to manage a particular application. These will typically run on slave nodes. However, it is not a single point of failure since it is not a machine but a process. If the Application Master fails, YARN will start a new Application Master.

Answer (score 2):

Hadoop2 uses two-level architecture:

1. RM schedules resource for each job, and RM will manage each job.
2. Application Master apply resource for single job and schedules applied resource for the job's tasks. Different jobs will use different type of Application Master, such as MapReduceAM、SparkAM

As for MapReduce job, if the job's MapReduceAM fails, YARN will launch a new MapReduceAM for the job util the job fails three times.

More details can be seen on Hadoop wiki